# solana cli paper wallets generating a different pubkey

Tags: solana, solana-cli

When creating a paper wallet with the solana cli and then running the seed phrase back into the cli I get a completely different pubkey?

What am I missing here?

*Not using a passphase in this example.*

```
❯ solana-keygen new --no-outfile

Generating a new keypair

For added security, enter a BIP39 passphrase

NOTE! This passphrase improves security of the recovery seed phrase NOT the
keypair file itself, which is stored as insecure plain text

BIP39 Passphrase (empty for none): none

===============================================================================
pubkey: 7A5h8N21EtjAnfcf8kxp7Bd7pNtQ5SvoYHLyBwz2796e
===============================================================================
Save this seed phrase and your BIP39 passphrase to recover your new keypair:
animal flock border attitude simple piece firm reason snack isolate siege seven
===============================================================================

~/.config/solana
❯ solana-keygen pubkey prompt://

[pubkey recovery] seed phrase: 
[pubkey recovery] If this seed phrase has an associated passphrase, enter it now. Otherwise, press ENTER to continue: 
2NW5bHw8dh4rS9wZSPj5u6Xec9tCHEN64PiTPUiy2ms7
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit confusing between the BIP44 and BIP39 derivation paths.  The seed phrase shown `animal flock border attitude simple piece firm reason snack isolate siege seven` comes from the legacy derivation, so it should be used with the `ASK` keyword instead of the `prompt://` keyword.

If you want to recover the expected public key, you'll have to run:

```
$ solana-keygen pubkey ASK
```

More information found towards the bottom of this section of the docs: https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/paper-wallet#public-key-derivation